# useMutation not mutating the local state

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I'm getting this error while trying to mutate the local state in apollo.

> errInvariant Violation: Expecting a parsed GraphQL document. Perhaps you need to wrap the query string in a "gql" tag? http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-client/core.html#gql

Initial state

```
registration: {
    __typename: 'Registration',
    tempMerchantId: '',
    authorizeProfile: {
      __typename: 'AuthorizePersonProfile',
      nid_front: '',
      nid_back: '',
      authorized_person_photo: ''
    }
  }
```

My mutation

```
export const setAuthorizePersonQuery = gql`
    mutation setAuthorizePersonProfileInfo($authorizePerosnData: Object!){
        setAuthorizePersonProfileInfo(authorizePersonData: $authorizePerosnData) @client
    }
`;
```

My resolver

```
export const setAuthorizePersonProfileInfo = (
  _, { authorizePersonData }, { cache }
) => {
  try {
    const prevData = cache.readQuery({ getAuthorizePersonProfileQuery });
    cache.writeQuery({
      getAuthorizePersonProfileQuery,
      data: {
        registration: {
          __typename: 'Registration',
          authorizeProfile: {
            __typename: 'AuthorizePersonProfile',
            ...prevData.registration.authorizeProfile,
            ...authorizePersonData
          }
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`err${e}`);
  }
  return null;
};
```

I'm trying to mutate the local state on button press, the function is

```
const handlePressedNext = () => {
    Promise.all([
      setAuthorizePersonProfileInfo({
        variables: { authorizePersonData: generateNidData() }
      })
    ])
      .then(() => {
        navigation.navigate('Photograph');
      });
  };
```

`generateNidData` function is like bellow

```
const generateNidData = () => ({
    nid_front: nidFrontImage,
    nid_back: nidBackImage
  });
```

I'm new to apollo client. I can not understand what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAuthorizePersonProfileQuery` is not a valid option for `readQuery`. Presumably, you meant use `query` instead.